# How to write chinese character in a flash file with proper strokes defined?

Tags: flash

How to write chinese character in a flash file with proper strokes defined 
like: http://www.chinesetimeschool.com/en-us/study-tools/learn-chinese-characters/%E6%98%AF/

Comment: Did you try using **Arial unicode** font in your flash file (that font allows writing characters of Chinese, Japanese, Arabic etc)?

Comment: Actually I have no idea about flash. But I want to do chinese character writing animation by flash...

Comment: Well this forum is for developers with **programming** questions. I can only suggest you download **Flash** (now called **Animate CC**) and begin some basic animation tutorials. Eventually you can bring Chinese character as text (or image and trace it) then use as Mask to show some moving red "fill" on 2nd layer underneath. Look at **masking** tutorials for Flash, then you'll understand how that site did it...

Comment: thanks for your helpful suggestion...